# Stuck on arrays

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm a student and I can't figure out how to complete this assignment. Basically were supposed to automatically compute a checksum on a datafile and store that checksum in an unsigned int array. The name of the file is supposed to be stored in another parallel array, and the contents of the file are to be read into a char array to compute the checksum.

This is what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
//declare variables
string filePath;
void savefile();
char choice;
int i,a, b, sum;
sum = 0;
a = 0;
b = 0;
ifstream inFile;
//arrays
const int SUM_ARR_SZ = 100;
string fileNames[SUM_ARR_SZ];
unsigned int checkSums[SUM_ARR_SZ];
do{
    cout << "Please select: " << endl;
    cout << "   A) Compute checksum of specified file" << endl;
    cout << "   B) Verify integrity of specified file" << endl;
    cout << "   Q) Quit" << endl;
    cin >> choice;

    if (choice == 'a' || choice == 'A')
    {
        //open file in binary mode
        cout << "Specify the file path: " << endl;
        cin >> filePath;
        inFile.open(filePath.c_str(), ios::binary);

        //save file name
        fileNames[a] = filePath;
        a++;


        //use seekg and tellg to determine file size
        char Arr[100000];
        inFile.seekg(0, ios_base::end);
        int fileLen = inFile.tellg();
        inFile.seekg(0, ios_base::beg);
        inFile.read(Arr, fileLen);
        inFile.close();
        for (i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            sum += Arr[i];
        }
        //store the sum into checkSums array
        checkSums[b] = sum;
        b++;
        cout <<"    File checksum = "<< sum << endl;

    }
    if (choice == 'b' || choice == 'B')
    {
        cout << "Specify the file path: " << endl;
        cin >> filePath;
        if (strcmp(filePath.c_str(), fileNames[a].c_str())==0)
        {

        }
    }
} while (choice != 'q' && choice != 'Q');
system("pause");
}
```

And an example of what our output is supposed to be(the 'a' is user input):

```
Please select:
A) Compute checksum of specified file
B) Verify integrity of specified file
Q) Quit
a
Specify the file path: c:\temp\tmp1
File checksum = 1530
Please select:
A) Compute checksum of specified file
B) Verify integrity of specified file
Q) Quit
```

Update: I've got the first part of the program sorted out now, the one which checks the sum. The problem I have now is getting the output correct for if you select B on the menu. 
It's supposed to check both arrays and make sure the name is right and make sure that the checksums are the same, but I'm completely lost on how to put that into code.

Comment: Your code is assuming the file length is always the same.

Comment: A couple of general rules, more valuable than any specific solution: 1) develop new functionality in isolation, and 2) if you're having trouble solving a problem, try solving a simpler problem. In this case, you have an array of strings and you want to search it for a given string. So write some code that will do that, and don't integrate it into the rest of your code until you have it working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to read from file char by char.
File length is unknown.
Do this untill End Of File:

```
inFile.seekg(0, ios_base::end);
int fileLen = inFile.tellg();
inFile.seekg(0, ios_base::beg);
for(int i =0; i<fileLen; i++)
{
    char Arr[1];
    inFile.read(Arr, 1);
    sum += Arr[0];    
}
inFile.close();
```

//sum is your answer

Comment: I think you are in error. `Arr` has already been filled with the file content.

Comment: @ David C. Rankin : That's not a problem. What do you mean?

Comment: While it is **not a problem.**, it also doesn't accomplish anything that hasn't already been done with `inFile.read(Arr, fileLen);`. You are free to **re-read** the file into `Arr` that was already read into `Arr` 1-line before the `for` loop, but it is just repetitive code and a redefinition of `Arr`. Do you not see `inFile.read(Arr, fileLen);`?

Comment: Your are right about that. I used `while` before and change it to `for` .

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the limit of your `for` loop. You have it reading `100000` times regardless of the length of the file. Changing `100000` to `fileLen` limits the read to each character read into `Arr`:

```
for (i = 0; i < fileLen; i++) {
    sum += Arr[i];
}
```

**output:**

```
$ ./bin/cscpp
Please select:
   A) Compute checksum of specified file
   B) Verify integrity of specified file
   Q) Quit
a
Specify the file path:
tmpkernel315.txt

    File checksum = 46173
```

Comment: I'm getting a large negative number for the output still and I'm not sure why. With the input file being only a few letters.

Comment: You have some interesting things taking place. You need to make sure you are in fact opening the file successfully, before beginning the read. Check `if (inFile.is_open)` and condition your read on a successful opening. I suspect you may be reading from a bad stream.